# Start a background task when value changed java

Tags: java, android, background-task

I am developing a sensor based application where I collect the sensors' data through BLE connection continuously and display it on a graph(s). I would like to add to the app an algorithm that will run on each new value received and display the result in the UI. As data transmission is done continuously, I would like that the algorithm will run on the background so the data to graph will keep to be in speed.
I was reading on several methods (AsyncTask, Thread etc...) but as a newbie: 
1. I don't fully understand which is better
2. I couldn't implement it correctly.

Here is the relevant piece of code:

```
         public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {
//Call to the algorithm class    
RespAlgo myAlgo = new RespAlgo();
        @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Code to initiate the graphs...
        }
         private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback =
                    new BluetoothGattCallback() { 
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) 
        {
        // Here I catch the data from the BLE device
         for (int i_bt_nTs = 0; i_bt_nTs < getResources().getInteger(R.integer.bt_nTs); i_bt_nTs++) {
                                //V2V8, S1, S2, S3
                                // k = R3/(Rs + R4) = V2V8/(ADCval * LSB / Gain + V2V8/2) - 1
                                // Rs = R3/k - R4

                                v2v8_val = v2v8_2_bval * 2 * adc_lsb * vbat_correction;
                                k = v2v8_val / (characteristic.getIntValue(FORMAT_UINT16, 2 + 6 * i_bt_nTs) * adc_lsb / ina_gain + v2v8_val / 2) - 1;
                                rs1 = R3 / k - R4;

                                //run the algorithm. the below should move to parallel task
                                // Add counter to the algorithm
                                        myAlgo.addTime();
                                //Add value from the sensor to the algorithm
                                        myAlgo.setValue(rs1);
                                //Return result to rr1 variable
                                        rr1 = (float)myAlgo.getRR();
                                 // Change the UI with the new value
                                        myRR1.setText(String.valueOf(rr1));

        }
        }
```

Comment: Most likely, AsyncTask is the best solution. It provides a higher-level abstraction for concurrency than Thread.

Comment: AsyncTask might be a problem as it is based on a fixed size threadpool and causes issue when large number of tasks are queued for execution.

Comment: If you think your activity might stop, or change, then use a service and report back to the activity.

Comment: @Linxy, what do you mean by stop or change?

Comment: Well the user might navigate away from it, open another activity or close the app, while your algorithm is running.

Comment: @Linxy There is currently only start button to start the measurement. no other activities accept Google maps that works on a fragment and the algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Create a local service and let your sensor data receiving code bind to this local service. Once bound, you can send messages to the service and let it process it in background and update the UI or whatever. You may read more about service here - https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Another new construct is using an event bus which will keep your code quite decoupled and does away with much of the luggage (You being new to Android will find this easier ). Check here - https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-use-the-eventbus-library--cms-22694

Comment: Thanks, I will check both Service and Eventbus.